# Dominated convergence theorem with function $\frac{1}{x^{\frac12+\frac1n}}\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{x}\right)^n$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> For $n\geqslant 3$ and $x\in(0,\infty)$, we define $$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\frac12+\frac1n}}\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{x}\right)^n.$$
>   I have to calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[1,\infty)} f_n(x)\,dx.$$

Of course, I have to use the dominated convergence theorem. I have to bound $|f_n(x)|$ by an integrable function independent of $n$.

I can think of using the inequality $|\sin u|\leq |u|$, but this gives me

$$
|f_n(x)|\leq \frac{\pi^n}{x^{\frac12+\frac1n+n}}
$$

I can use that $x\geq 1$ so $x^{1/n+n}\geq 1$, but this leaves me with the $\pi^n$ term that seems to diverge.

Could someone provide any help?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to bound by
$$
\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)^n x^{-1/2-1/n}
$$
so $\int_\pi^\infty$ would converge since $\pi < x$, and $\int_1^\pi$ is on a compact interval and the integrand is bounded as well...

Comment: I have to find an integrate majorant on $]\pi,\infty[$ which is independent of $n$, how would I do that? Because $1/\sqrt{x}$ is not integrable there.

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz for $[\pi,\infty)$ your sequence $f_n$ converges to the $0$ function.

Comment: I know that, but how do I find this integrable majorant then?

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz consider using monotone convergence theorem instead